# Simple submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am looking for example of module over a ring which has only simple submodules.

I think about $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ for prime $p$ but i want module which has more than 1 simple submodules.

Comment: try $F\times F$ as a module over itself, where $F$ is your favorite field. the only proper non-zero submodules are $F\times 0$ and $0\times F$, both of which are simple

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom : they're not the only ones. But they will all be $1$-dimensional and thus simple so your example still works

Comment: Read literally, requiring $R$ itself to be simple would make $R$ a field, and that completely characterizes such rings.  Do you really mean to ask for nontrivial ideals to be simple, as the above comments suggest?  Please edit to clarify. Please use a better title while you're at it.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi why not? note that I am taking $F\times F$ as a module over itself

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom : oh I thought you meant over $F$ ! Well I guess both work anyways, sorry about that :)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi no worries!! :) indeed both examples work well!